# How to use GCP REST API to execute a query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In GCP, Big Query editor, https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery, I can execute my query like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_downloads
FROM `the-psf.pypi.file_downloads`
WHERE file.project = 'pytest'
  -- Only query the last 30 days of history
  AND DATE(timestamp)
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

But when I try to use the REST API to execute the query, i.e.
go to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query
and click 'Try it', and put this in the request body:

```
{
  "query": "    #standardSQL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_downloads
    FROM `the-psf.pypi.file_downloads`
    WHERE file.project = 'pytest'
      -- Only query the last 30 days of history
      AND DATE(timestamp)
        BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
        AND CURRENT_DATE()"
}
```

I get error like "Select an underlined section to see more details.
You have invalid or missing required parameter values above."
So how can I fix the problem in order to use the Query REST API?

Comment: You are only filling out the `query` field. Review the required fields. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#QueryRequest Example: `"kind":"bigquery#queryRequest","useLegacySql":false,"query":YOUR_QUERY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON spec doesn't support multiline string. You need to flatten your string

```
{
  "query": "#standardSQL \n SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_downloads FROM `the-psf.pypi.file_downloads` WHERE file.project = 'pytest' \n -- Only query the last 30 days of history \n AND DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE()"
}
```

You also need to add a `\n` to isolate the comments (standardSQL and you comment in the middle of your query)